# Pass environment variables through build parameters to pipeline node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized pipeline build with one 'String' parameter `BuildOutDir` with value `${WORKSPACE}/out/`.

My pipeline script is:

```
node ('windows') {
    stage ('Test') {
        echo "$WORKSPACE"
        echo "$BuildOutDir"
        }
}
```

Output is :

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
D:\jenkins\workspace\test_pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
${WORKSPACE}\out\
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Is there a way to expand environment variable passed as build parameter ? This expands correctly in non-pipeline build jobs.

Comment: `Eval.me("$BuildOutDir")` should work... But can't you just pass `\out` and add it to `WORKSPACE`?

Comment: @tim_yates ... I used `WORKSPACE` as an example for an environment variable. I tried `Eval.me("$BuildOutDir")`, it gives me an error `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token:  @ line 1, column 18.${WORKSPACE}/out/
                    ^

1 error `. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't show the script or job that call this pipeline.

However, it is most likely due to incorrect [string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation). In groovy, you need to use double quotes so variables get interpolated (= replaced). If instead you used simple quote, the param string will not be interpreted and your workspace variable will not be replaced. So basically what you want to do is replace the following line :

```
build job: 'yourPipeline', parameters: [string(name: 'BuildOutDir', value: '${WORKSPACE}')]
```

With :

```
build job: 'yourPipeline', parameters: [string(name: 'BuildOutDir', value: "${WORKSPACE}")]
```

in your calling pipeline. Again, the only difference is the double quotes instead of the single quotes aroung `${WORKSPACE}` variable
.

Comment: @Pom12.........the script above is in the parent job (and no downstream jobs). I'm using  `Parameterized Builds` jenkins plug-in to pass parameters to job on triggering it.

Comment: So the parent job is à freestyle job right ? Still, context is essential here, please provide a snippet of code or a screenshot of the parent job call